# Update index based on array of values in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to update(literally sort) the manual index based on another array of values(ms).

### Input

```
String ms[] = { "10","11","14","12"};
String indx[]={ "0", "1", "2", "3" }; // Manual index based on ms values`
```

### Expected Output

`String indx[]= { "0", "1", "3", "2"}; // After updating`

### Input(on new input)

```
String ms[] = { "10","11","14","12","13"};         
String indx[]={ "0", "1", "3", "2" ,"4"};
```

### Expected Output

`String indx[]= { "0", "1", "4", "2" ,"3"};`

How to achieve this in Java. 
I have tried **TreeMap, Sort, Comparator impl**. But all gives sorted array.

But i need something will update the index instead of sort.

Comment: I don't understand the second example.  Should the order not be `{0, 1, 2, 4, 3}` ?

Comment: make a `class T` that `implements Comparable<? super T>` with a private field for `ms`. Put any instances of that class into some sort of sorting data structure such as a `TreeSet<T>` and you are good to go. Or simply add the instances to a `List<T>` and call `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . Second example is for new record we received. On every record we receive, we update the index based on ms[] array of values. I gave two examples for better understanding. Hope i made you understand.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is make a class that implements Comparable with a private field for the milliseconds and the index. Put any instances of that class into some sort of sorting data structure such as a TreeSet and you are good to go. Or simply add the instances to a List and call Collections.sort(). Below is the full class with working example.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Milli implements Comparable<Milli> {
    private int ms, index;

    public Milli (int ms, int index) {
        this.ms = ms;
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return Integer.toString(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo (Milli o) {
        return Integer.compare(ms, o.ms);
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Set<Milli> set = new TreeSet<>();
        String ms[] = { "10","11","14","12"};
        String indx[]={ "0", "1", "2", "3" }; // Manual index based on ms values
        for (int i=0; i<ms.length; i++)
            set.add(new Milli(Integer.parseInt(ms[i]), Integer.parseInt(indx[i])));
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

Comment: If `ms[]` had duplicate values in that case TreeSet will not add those duplicate values, where as in the solution given below @saka1029, this will not happen. You will have to update the compareTo() to return something like this `int compare = Integer.compare(ms, o.ms);
 return compare == 0 ? 1 : compare;`

Comment: Thank you @WillSherwood for your answer. You can see my answer below and help on improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for your answers. Somehow i achieved it by using following code. This works as expected but performance wise i am not sure.

Please review and comment.

```
long lastMsValue = Long.valueOf(ms[ms.length-1]);
int crntIndx = 65350; //Assuming not more than 1000 records.

    if(ms.length == indx.length){
        if(ms.length == 2 && Long.valueOf(ms[0]) > lastMsValue){
            indx[0]="1";
            indx[1]="0";                
        }else if(ms.length > 2){
            for(int m=0;m<ms.length-1;m++){
                if (Long.valueOf(ms[m]) > lastMsValue){
                    if(crntIndx > m)
                        crntIndx = m;
                }else if(Long.valueOf(ms[m]) == lastMsValue){
                    crntIndx = m;
                }
            }

            indx[indx.length-1] = String.valueOf(crntIndx);
            System.out.println("Crnt Indx = " + crntIndx + "   And Indx Array Value ");
            for(int m=0;m<ms.length-1;m++){
                if (Long.valueOf(ms[m]) > lastMsValue)
                    indx[m] = String.valueOf(Integer.valueOf(indx[m])+1);
            }
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Lengths are not equal and sorting is not done");
    }
```